# Allowing admins and authors to edit data in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.4

How do I (safely) allow only admins and authors to edit data in CakePHP, without referring to hard-coded group IDs?

I'm using Auth and ACL in my CakePHP 2.4 app, so ordinarily I would just restrict the edit action to admins and moderators, but I also need to allow authors to edit data they've created.

I currently have this in my `edit` method, which works, but uses hard-coded values, which is bad practice: I set the ACLS to allow `edit` by default, and the controller redirects if the user is neither author nor admin.

Is there a way to respect the ACL settings (thus avoiding hard-coded group ids), while punching a hole through them for post authors?

```
if ($this->Auth->user('id') != $this->Post->field('user_id')) {
    if ($this->Auth->user('group_id') > 2) {

    $this->Session->setFlash(__('You are not authorized to edit this post.'), 'flash/error');
    $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at [CakePHP's documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html#authorization-who-s-allowed-to-access-what) about authorization. It might shed some light on your question.

Answer (score 2):

You can store authors 'id or name' to enable edition it's own.
You can check rows 'admin or author or guest' to check for editing all contents.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html#authorization-who-s-allowed-to-access-what

This is already in documentation

```
public function isAuthorized($user) {
    // All registered users can add posts
    if ($this->action === 'add') {
        return true;
    }

    // The owner of a post can edit and delete it
    if (in_array($this->action, array('edit', 'delete'))) {
        $postId = $this->request->params['pass'][0];
        if ($this->Post->isOwnedBy($postId, $user['id'])) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return parent::isAuthorized($user);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

[Follow CakePHP book](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html).

I hope `Controller::isAuthorized()` and `Post::isOwnedBy()` in the article is your purpose.